# How do I execute a count command using scala.dbc?

Tags: sql-server, scala

I am trying to connect to an MS/SQL server and execute a 'count' statement. I've reached this far:

```
import scala.dbc._
import scala.dbc.Syntax._
import scala.dbc.syntax.Statement._
import java.net.URI

object MsSqlVendor extends Vendor {
    val uri = new URI("jdbc:sqlserver://173.248.X.X:Y/DataBaseName")
    val user = "XXX"
    val pass = "XXX"

    val retainedConnections = 5
    val nativeDriverClass = Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); 
    val urlProtocolString = "jdbc:sqlserver:"
}

object Main {
      def main(args: Array[String]) {
      println("Hello, world!")

      val db = new Database(MsSqlVendor)

      val count = db.executeStatement {
        select (count) from (technical)
        }


      println("%d rows counted", count)
      }
}
```

I get an error saying: "scala.dbc.syntax.Statement.select of type dbc.syntax.Statement.SelectZygote does not take parameters"

How do I set this up?

Answer (score 0):

This can be a problem:

```
val count = db.executeStatement {
        select (count) from (technical)
        }
```

The `count` inside the statement refers to `val count`, not to some other `count`. Still, there's the other problem you report. There's neither a `count` nor a `technical` definition anywhere. Maybe it is missing from some other place where you found this snippet. The following does compile, though it's anyone's guess as to whether it does what you want:

```
val countx = db.executeStatement {
    select fields "count" from "technical"
}
```

At any rate, I thought scala.dbc was long deprecated. I can't find any deprecation notice, however, and it is still linked on the library jar, even on trunk.

Comment: I have a table called 'technical'. Following your tip, I got the code to compile. Now I get a runtime error: Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'count'

Comment: A table in the database or a table definition in scala code? A table on the database is not visible as a definition from scala. And I _thought_ you wanted to do `count(*)`, but I don't know how to do that, or even if that's possible with `scala.dbc`.

Comment: old school code that works:       val uri = "jdbc:sqlserver://173.248.X.Y:1125;databaseName=V;user=XXX;password=YYY;"
      val nativeDriverClass = Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") 
      val conn = DriverManager.getConnection(uri)
     
      val statement = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)
      val countxx = statement.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM technical")

      countxx.next
      println("rows counted: " + countxx.getString("cnt"))

Comment: @Sunder No one uses `scala.dbc`. If you want a good sql library, I recommend ScalaQuery.